# onscroll firing when other events are being listened for?

Tags: javascript, ios

On iOS, it seems that if you have a function to run `onscroll` in the same document with an event listener, the `onscroll` event will fire sporadically.

#### Here's an example, although you must use a device running iOS for this: http://jsfiddle.net/a3D7J/3/

The code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("content").onscroll = function() {
    alert("test");
}
    
$("#content").on('touchmove', function() {
   
});​
```

The expected behavior is for the `onscroll` event to be fired once the scrolling is complete:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Can anybody think of a solution to this? I need to detect when the page stops moving after a finger swipe.

Comment: btw, in chrome, if you scroll by scroll border it will also fire event, before you end scroll.

Comment: Yea. It also is fired when you scroll on Safari.